# What would happen if water is to flow through a microchannel where its top is hydrophilic and bottom hydrophobic?

Tags: water

What would happen if water is to flow through a microchannel where its top is hydrophilic and bottom hydrophobic?

If an external pressure is applied, for example, a syringe pump is used, it is expected that water will flow through the microchannel, even if the channel is completely hydrophobic.

I wonder what is the situation when only the capillary force is the driving force, when the two surfaces of the channel are different in their wettability.